# How do I change the Ctrl+Tab behavior in dolphin file manager?

Tags: dolphin-file-manager

How do I change the Ctrl+Tab behavior in dolphin so that it goes to the last open tab instead of cycling the tabs in order? This is an important functionality for me so I might even switch file managers if it is not feasible enough to implement. I could not find any options in the builtin settings. The builtin settings in fact are limiting for me. I would be fine to switch to another file manager if it has this feature.